# Intermittent failures when VPC peering from different accounts in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc

I'm accessing redis on AWS account B from VPC ECS on AWS account A, and I'm getting the following error:

> redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 110 connecting to my_redis:6379. Connection timed out

It intermittently succeeds and mostly gets a connection timeout.

Why does redis connection fail most of the time?

I think I've got the VPC pairing and routing set up correctly on both accounts. Why is this happening?

Comment: Can you include the error message that you are getting?  Also, I'm guessing you mean you are using VPC Peering, not pairing?

Comment: I get an error like this
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 110 connecting to my_redis:6379. Connection timed out.
Sometimes it's a success.
VPC peering. Thanks!

Comment: I see.  It is odd that it is intermittent.  To me, that points to the idea that it may be a code issue.  I would recommend you use the VPC Reachability Analyzer and see if it indicates any issues with the route.  If that comes back with no issues, can you post your code?